# How to deploy python Google Cloud Function with local dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-python

I have a few `google-cloud-functions` that has common code between them.
So I chose to make a package and place it on each of the folders for my functions.
ending with the following directory structure

```
google-cloud-function
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
└── helpers
    ├── tools.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I followed [Packaging Local Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#packaging_local_dependencies) from the docs to make my package `helpers`.
With my `requirements.txt` as follow:

```
firebase-admin==4.0.0
google-cloud-storage==1.26.0
google-cloud-firestore==1.6.2
```

The function deploys properly but when triggered crashes with no logs.
This is the import statement.

```
from helpers.tools import Event, CleanUpUser
```

How can I deploy this `python` `google-cloud-function` appropiately?

EDIT:
`main.py`

```
import firebase_admin
from google.cloud import firestore

from helpers.tools import Event

firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={'databaseURL': 'https://database_name.firebaseio.com/'})
firestore_db = firestore.Client()

EVENTS_NAME = 'database-events'


def user_cleanup(data, context):
    if Event(EVENTS_NAME).check_event(context):
        return 'Done'
    user_id = data['uid']
    user_ref = firestore_db.document(f'user_data/{user_id}')
    return 'Done'
```

`tools.py`

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback
from datetime import datetime

import firebase_admin
import pytz
from google.cloud import firestore


class Event:
    def __init__(self, database_name: str):
        init_logger()
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={'databaseURL': 'https://{database_name}.firebaseio.com/'})

    def check_event(self, context):
        event_id = context.event_id.replace('/', '--')
        timestamp = context.timestamp
        timestamp = timestamp[0:23] if len(timestamp) >= 24 else timestamp[0:19]
        try:
            millis = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).timestamp()*1000
        except ValueError:
            millis = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).timestamp()*1000
        event_ref = firebase_admin.db.reference().child(event_id)
        event = event_ref.get()
        if not event:
            event_ref.set({
                'timestamp': millis
            })
            return False
        else:
            logging.warning('Event already in the list, exiting this instance.')
            return True
```

EDIT: My issue is that I wasn't formatting the `databaseURL` by prepending an `f`, still I was able to debug that using a `try/catch` the logs never showed the cause of the error only `...finished with status: 'crash'`, opened an issue in the [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/4005)

Comment: This pattern should work, is it possible that you have an error elsewhere? Can you include your `main.py` and `tools.py`? Are you able to run this locally and verify that it workrs? You can run it locally with the Functions Framework: https://pypi.org/project/functions-framework/

Comment: @DustinIngram I have added `main.py` and `tools.py`. I have not tried locally, I do not get errors on deployment but the function crashes when triggered without any `log`.
`vscode` does give me a warning about the import. `__init__.py` is empty.

Comment: @DustinIngram I just tried the `functions-framework` and it works as expected, although I just modified my scripts to check for the class being imported appropriately

Comment: What makes you think the import is failing? If it deploys successfully, but fails when it is triggered, that indicates that something in the function itself is causing the crash. When you say "crashes with no logs", what do you see that indicates a crash?

Comment: @DustinIngram I really don't know is the import is the one that is failing. But the log shows only that `Function execution started` and then in the next line `Function execution took 1168 ms, finished with status: 'crash'` with no other info.
I've put some print statements and they don't show up, not even after the `entry-point`, I have one right after the `user_clean_up` definition.

Comment: @DustinIngram the issue was that I did not added a `f` format to the `databaseURL` when initializing firebase. But I was able to debug that only with a `try/catch`, the logs only shows `... finished with status: 'crash'`

Comment: This is a known issue that's in the process of being fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191